# SQL update many lines with one condiiton

Tags: sql, sqlite

SQL table:  contact_id | phone.

Every `contact_id` has many phone numbers, so the table would be the following:

```
1  123456
1  567348
2  065879
1  778899
2  002030
...
```

For instance, I need to replace the first contact's phone numbers with 112233, 223344, 334455.

```
    $stmt = $connection->prepare( "UPDATE phones SET phone='$phone1' WHERE contact_id=?;");
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt = $connection->prepare( "UPDATE phones SET phone='$phone2' WHERE contact_id=?;");
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt = $connection->prepare( "UPDATE phones SET phone='$phone3' WHERE contact_id=?;");
    $stmt->execute();
```

It seems to have replaced all three rows with the last phone (334455). Actually, I have not tried it yet, but it is obvious. How to replace the phone numbers correctly?

```
 123456 -> 112233
 567348 -> 223344
 778899 -> 334455
```

Comment: after execution of all three prepared statements the last statement is going to overwrite the phone column for the specified contact id. which leaves you with 334455.

Comment: There is not a simple way to do this without knowing the original phone numbers.  Do you have other columns in the table?

Answer (score 1):

Given the constraints as you have defined them, the only way I can think is along these lines:

```
update phones
    set phone = $phone1
    where contact_id = ?
    limit 1;

update phones
    set phone = $phone2
    where contact_id = ? and phone not in ($phone1)
    limit 1;

update phones
    set phone = $phone3
    where contact_id = ? and phone not in ($phone1, $phone2)
    limit 1;
```

However, you should fix the data structure.  Or, better yet, delete the existing rows and insert new one:

```
delete phones
    where contact_id = ?;

insert into phones(contact_id, phone)
    values (?, $phone1), (?, $phone2) (?, $phone3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your database model is faulty. You need to define a primary key for the table, such as in:

```
create table phones (
  contact_id int not null,
  phone_id int not null,
  phone varchar(20) not null,
  constraint pk_phones primary key (contact_id, phone_id)
);
```

Then, updating becomes easy:

```
update phones set phone = '334455'
  where contact_id = 1 and phone_id = 3;
```

If you don't add the primary key, you won't have a clear way of identifying rows, and you'll be looking for trouble. That's the purpose of primary keys.